# VSCode Docker image size inflated to 9GB on Alpine, seeking optimization

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm facing a perplexing issue while developing a Docker image for VSCode using Alpine Linux (specifically alpine:3.7.1). Despite my efforts, the resulting image size balloons to around 9GB, which is unreasonably large compared to compiled VSCode images I've encountered elsewhere.

my DockerFile:

```
# Set default values for build arguments
ARG NODE_VERSION=18.17.1
ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.17.2

# Build Node.js stage
FROM node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine AS node

# Build final image with Alpine Linux
FROM alpine:${ALPINE_VERSION}

# Copy Node.js binaries from the build stage
COPY --from=node /usr/lib /usr/lib
COPY --from=node /usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib
COPY --from=node /usr/local/include /usr/local/include
COPY --from=node /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin

# Install required dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    bash \
    git \
    build-base \
    g++ \
    libx11-dev \
    libxkbfile-dev \
    libsecret-dev \
    krb5-dev \
    python3 \
    fakeroot \
    rpm

# Clean up caches
RUN rm -rf ~/.cache/node-gyp

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /vscode

# Copy project files
COPY . .

# Install Yarn and Node.js dependencies
RUN npm install -g yarn --force && yarn

# Expose port
EXPOSE 8443

# Run VS Code build with Bash
CMD ["./scripts/code-server.sh", "--without-connection-token", "--port", "8443", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Despite following best practices and utilizing Alpine Linux, I'm puzzled by the drastic increase in size of my repository's mere 40 MB to a whopping 2.39 GB after compiling locally.

Any insights or suggestions on how to optimize my Dockerfile and reduce the image size would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!